# Views centered in parent below each other

Tags: swift, swift3, ios-autolayout, cosmicmind

I'm trying to make this view with the Layout extension, I tried a little bit, but can't figure it out. 
[image: Desired result]

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var nameField: TextField!
    private var emailField: ErrorTextField!
    private var passwordField: TextField!

    private let constant: CGFloat = 32

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = Color.indigo.base

        prepareNameField()
        preparePasswordField()
        prepareResignResponderButton()
    }

    /// Prepares the resign responder button.
    private func prepareResignResponderButton() {
        let btn = FlatButton(title: "Login", titleColor: Color.white)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleResignResponderButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.layout(btn).width(100).height(constant).right(0).top(8 * constant).horizontally(left: constant, right: constant);
    }

    /// Handle the resign responder button.
    @objc
    internal func handleResignResponderButton(button: UIButton) {
        nameField?.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField?.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    private func prepareNameField() {
        nameField = TextField()
        nameField.placeholderNormalColor = Color.indigo.lighten4
        nameField.placeholderActiveColor = Color.white
        nameField.dividerNormalColor = Color.indigo.lighten4
        nameField.dividerActiveColor = Color.white
        nameField.isClearIconButtonEnabled = true
        nameField.textColor = Color.white
        nameField.placeholder = "Username"

        view.layout(nameField).top(4 * constant).horizontally(left: constant, right: constant)
    }

    private func preparePasswordField() {
        passwordField = TextField()
        passwordField.placeholderNormalColor = Color.indigo.lighten4
        passwordField.placeholderActiveColor = Color.white
        passwordField.dividerNormalColor = Color.indigo.lighten4
        passwordField.dividerActiveColor = Color.white
        passwordField.isClearIconButtonEnabled = true
        passwordField.textColor = Color.white
        passwordField.placeholder = "Password"
        passwordField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        passwordField.isVisibilityIconButtonEnabled = true

        // Setting the visibilityIconButton color.
        passwordField.visibilityIconButton?.tintColor = Color.white.withAlphaComponent(passwordField.isSecureTextEntry ? 0.38 : 0.54)

        view.layout(passwordField).top(6 * constant).horizontally(left: constant, right: constant)
    }

}
```

I'm new to swift so if someone can explain me how to accomplish it that would be great.

Comment: Does it have to be done with Layout extensions or is normal Swift layout code fine?

Comment: @Zhang I was looking at this documentation http://www.cosmicmind.com/material/layout but if it's not possible or you don't know it. It's a start to get it done in normal Swift layout code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with the author's idea of "simple". Seems more complicated than normal iOS auto layout codes, at the very least, you have to remember all these "edges", "vertically", "horizontally", "interimSpacing" etc. I'll provide an answer below with how I would do it using normal Autolayout code.

Comment: @Zhang That would be great!

Comment: Hey, The Layout extension is meant for simple use cases and that scales with ones knowledge on the API. For example, positioning something in the bottom left, is view.layout(button).bottomLeft(). I don't think it can get easier than that. Once you start combining multiple views together where they influence each other, you would either need experience with the Layout API, or use the Grid API, or use AutoLayout or frames itself. This is where you make the choice of what is best for you. My suggestion would be to always understand what is really going on, and then choose to use abstracted layers

Comment: That said, if you would like for me to help get you there, we can do that in the [Gitter Material](https://gitter.im/CosmicMind/Material) chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][image]Here is an example with TextFields.

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var emailField: ErrorTextField!
    fileprivate var passwordField: TextField!

    /// A constant to layout the textFields.
    fileprivate let constant: CGFloat = 32

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = Color.grey.lighten5

        preparePasswordField()
        prepareEmailField()
        prepareResignResponderButton()
    }

    /// Prepares the resign responder button.
    fileprivate func prepareResignResponderButton() {
        let btn = RaisedButton(title: "Resign", titleColor: Color.blue.base)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleResignResponderButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.layout(btn).width(100).height(constant).centerVertically(offset: emailField.height / 2 + 60).right(20)
    }

    /// Handle the resign responder button.
    @objc
    internal func handleResignResponderButton(button: UIButton) {
        emailField?.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    fileprivate func prepareEmailField() {
        emailField = ErrorTextField()
        emailField.placeholder = "Email"
        emailField.detail = "Error, incorrect email"
        emailField.isClearIconButtonEnabled = true
        emailField.delegate = self

        view.layout(emailField).center(offsetY: -passwordField.height - 60).left(20).right(20)

    }

    fileprivate func preparePasswordField() {
        passwordField = TextField()
        passwordField.placeholder = "Password"
        passwordField.detail = "At least 8 characters"
        passwordField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        passwordField.isVisibilityIconButtonEnabled = true

        // Setting the visibilityIconButton color.
        passwordField.visibilityIconButton?.tintColor = Color.green.base.withAlphaComponent(passwordField.isSecureTextEntry ? 0.38 : 0.54)

        view.layout(passwordField).center().left(20).right(20)
    }
}


extension UIViewController: TextFieldDelegate {
    public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        (textField as? ErrorTextField)?.isErrorRevealed = false
    }

    public func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        (textField as? ErrorTextField)?.isErrorRevealed = false
        return true
    }

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        (textField as? ErrorTextField)?.isErrorRevealed = false
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Working perfect.

Comment: I made a code update to have it handle orientation changes. Use the updated code :) I added `.left(20).right(20)` to every layout definition.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, with the visual formatting language, you're basically painting with code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var view1:UILabel!
    var view2:UILabel!
    var view3:UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        initViews();
        initLayouts();
    }

    func initViews() {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        view1 = createLabel(title: "view1")
        view2 = createLabel(title: "view2")
        view3 = createLabel(title: "view3")

        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)
        view.addSubview(view3)
    }

    func initLayouts() {
        for view in view.subviews {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }


        var views = [String: AnyObject]()
        views["view1"] = view1
        views["view2"] = view2
        views["view3"] = view3

        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // Setup horizontal constraints for all three views
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[view1]-20-|",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                           metrics: nil,
                                                           views: views))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[view2(==view1)]-20-|",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                           metrics: nil,
                                                           views: views))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[view3]-20-|",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                           metrics: nil,
                                                           views: views))

        // special layout condition to make third view half the width of other views
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: view1,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
                                              multiplier: 0.5,
                                              constant: 0.0))




        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // Setup vertical constraints for all three views
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[view1]-20-[view2]-20-[view3]",
                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                           metrics: nil,
                                           views: views))

        // make all three views equal height
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view1(44)]",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                           metrics: nil,
                                                           views: views))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view2(==view1)]",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                           metrics: nil,
                                                           views: views))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view3(==view1)]",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                           metrics: nil,
                                                           views: views))
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Helper function
    // ------------------------------------------------
    func createLabel(title:String) -> UILabel {
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.text = title
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        textLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

        return textLabel
    }
}
```

You should see something like this:

[image: screenshot]